# Кнопка Delete не работает при добавление задачи

Tags: javascript, dom

Когда добавляю задачу в этом конкретном карточки кнопка delete не работает но когда список задач рендеритса из массива про загрузке страницы то тогда всё работает правильно. Пожалуйста помогите понять как сделать так чтобы кнопка Delete работала на конкретном задачи которые я добавил

```js
const tasks = [
  {
    _id: '5d2ca9e2e03d40b326596aa7',
    completed: true,
    body:
      'Occaecat non ea quis occaecat ad culpa amet deserunt incididunt elit fugiat pariatur. Exercitation commodo culpa in veniam proident laboris in. Excepteur cupidatat eiusmod dolor consectetur exercitation nulla aliqua veniam fugiat irure mollit. Eu dolor dolor excepteur pariatur aute do do ut pariatur consequat reprehenderit deserunt.\r\n',
    title: 'Eu ea incididunt sunt consectetur fugiat non.',
  },
  {
    _id: '5d2ca9e29c8a94095c1288e0',
    completed: false,
    body:
      'Aliquip cupidatat ex adipisicing veniam do tempor. Lorem nulla adipisicing et esse cupidatat qui deserunt in fugiat duis est qui. Est adipisicing ipsum qui cupidatat exercitation. Cupidatat aliqua deserunt id deserunt excepteur nostrud culpa eu voluptate excepteur. Cillum officia proident anim aliquip. Dolore veniam qui reprehenderit voluptate non id anim.\r\n',
    title:
      'Deserunt laborum id consectetur pariatur veniam occaecat occaecat tempor voluptate pariatur nulla reprehenderit ipsum.',
  },
  {
    _id: '5d2ca9e2e03d40b3232496aa7',
    completed: true,
    body:
      'Occaecat non ea quis occaecat ad culpa amet deserunt incididunt elit fugiat pariatur. Exercitation commodo culpa in veniam proident laboris in. Excepteur cupidatat eiusmod dolor consectetur exercitation nulla aliqua veniam fugiat irure mollit. Eu dolor dolor excepteur pariatur aute do do ut pariatur consequat reprehenderit deserunt.\r\n',
    title: 'Eu ea incididunt sunt consectetur fugiat non.',
  },
  {
    _id: '5d2ca9e29c8a94095564788e0',
    completed: false,
    body:
      'Aliquip cupidatat ex adipisicing veniam do tempor. Lorem nulla adipisicing et esse cupidatat qui deserunt in fugiat duis est qui. Est adipisicing ipsum qui cupidatat exercitation. Cupidatat aliqua deserunt id deserunt excepteur nostrud culpa eu voluptate excepteur. Cillum officia proident anim aliquip. Dolore veniam qui reprehenderit voluptate non id anim.\r\n',
    title:
      'Deserunt laborum id consectetur pariatur veniam occaecat occaecat tempor voluptate pariatur nulla reprehenderit ipsum.',
  },
];

(function(arrayTasks){

const objTasks = arrayTasks.reduce((acc, task) => {
  acc[task._id] = task;
  return acc;
}, {});

const container = document.querySelector('.tasks-list-section .list-group');
const form = document.forms['addTask'];
const inputTitle = form.elements['title'];
const inputBody = form.elements['body'];


renderAllTasks(objTasks);
form.addEventListener('submit', onFormSumbmitHandler);
container.addEventListener('click', onDeleteHandler);

function renderAllTasks(taskList) {
  if(!taskList) {
    console.error('Haven\'t found Object of Tasks ');
    return;
  }
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  Object.values(taskList).forEach(task => {
    const li = createHTML(task);
    fragment.appendChild(li);
  });
  container.appendChild(fragment);
}

function createHTML({body, title, _id}) {

  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.classList.add('list-group-item', 'd-flex', 'align-items-center', 'flex-wrap', 'mt-2');
  li.setAttribute('data-task-id', _id);

  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  span.textContent = title;

  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger', 'ml-auto', 'delete-btn');
  btn.textContent = 'Delete';

  const article = document.createElement('p');
  article.classList.add('mt-2', 'w-100');
  article.textContent = body;

  li.appendChild(span);
  li.appendChild(btn);
  li.appendChild(article);
  return li;
}

function onFormSumbmitHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const titleValue = inputTitle.value;
  const bodyValue = inputBody.value;
  if(!titleValue || !bodyValue) {
    alert('Please type Something');
    return;
  }
  const newObjTask = createNewTask(titleValue, bodyValue);
  const newItem = createHTML(newObjTask);
  container.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', newItem);
  form.reset();
}

function createNewTask(title, body) {
  const newTask = {
    _id: `task-${Math.random()}`,
    completed: false,
    body,
    title
  }
  objTasks[newTask._id] = newTask;
  return {...newTask};
}

function isConfirmHandler(id) {
  const {title} = objTasks[id];
  const isConfirm = confirm(`Are you sure to delete ${title}`);
  if(!isConfirm) return isConfirm;
  delete objTasks[id];
  return isConfirm;
}

function deleteTask(confirm, el) {
  if(!confirm) return;
  el.remove();
}

function onDeleteHandler({target}) {
  if(target.classList.contains('delete-btn')){
    const parent = target.closest('[data-task-id]');
    const id = parent.dataset.taskId;
    const confirm = isConfirmHandler(id);
    deleteTask(confirm, parent);
  }
}

})(tasks);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="form-section mt-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Add new task</h5>
                <form name="addTask">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="title"
                    id="title"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Task title"
                  />
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="body"
                    id="body"
                    class="form-control mt-3"
                    placeholder="Task body"
                  />
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">
                    Add task
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tasks-list-section mt-5">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="list-group">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы добавляете новую задачу не в тот элемент, который отслеживает события `click`, а рядом с ним.

```
  //container.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', newItem);
  container.insertBefore(newItem, container.firstChild);
```